# select and the PS3 variable

Tags: bash, vim, prompt

I have a small function that I keep in my profile to give me quick access to some config files:

```
viconf ()
{
    COLUMNS=12;
    printf "Edit config file:\n\n";
    select x in ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_login ~/.profile ~/.inputrc ~/.vimrc;
    do
        vim $x;
        break;
    done
}
```

It creates output like this:

```
1) /home/boss/.bashrc
2) /home/boss/.bash_profile
3) /home/boss/.bash_login
4) /home/boss/.profile
5) /home/boss/.inputrc
6) /home/boss/.vimrc
#?
```

I'm not really happy with this. I want the `#?` to have a `\n` and then say `Select a config file to edit with vi?`. I've tried lots of ways to edit `PS3` but everything I try fails to achieve this (specifically, the `\n` always fails). How do I make my function have a custom prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either insert a literal newline in the string:

```
PS3='
Select a config file to edit with vi? '
```

or use `printf` with a C-style `\n` for the newline:

```
PS3="$(printf '\nSelect a config file to edit with vi? ')"
```

or using the bash shell's `printf -v` to write to the variable directly

```
printf -v PS3 '\n%s ' 'Select a config file to edit with vi?'
```